# How to allocate PTY using Shake?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm trying to run a command interactively from my build script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
script
--resolver lts-18.8
--ghc-options -Wall
-}
import Development.Shake

main :: IO ()
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
  phony "cfg" $ do
    command_ [] "vim" []
```

But it does not work. I suppose I need to allocate a terminal to be able to run vim interactively. How can I do that?

Comment: For which operating system ??? On Linux, if your process cannot be run in a terminal passed from above, you would typically use something like `xterm -e /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/vim fileName"`. Can be improved by telling xterm which font to use, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Shake` functions for running commands (`command`, `cmd` etc) are designed for batch commands that run without user interaction. While there are things you can do to make them more compatible with something like Vim (e.g. `InheritStdin`) there are probably aspects of Shake that will make things harder (e.g. capturing the stderr, which might result in a memory leak).

Happily, Shake can work just as well with the functions in `System.Process`, so instead of calling `command` you can write:

```
liftIO $ System.Process.createProcess $ System.Process.shell "vim"
```

The `createProcess` takes a record with many types of process-related settings, so can be customised to make Vim work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in the end:
`createProcess $ proc "vim" [] >>= \(_, _, _, ph) -> waitForProcess ph`. Thanks for the explanation.